# R: Create a new column in r with concatenated values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

Here is a test dataset with one column of company names.

```
df <- data.frame(companyName= c("Apple", "Microsoft", "Perspectives", "Jet", "Icontel AG","Intel"))
```

I would like to concatenate these names and add them to a new column in the dataframe

I tried the following using a for loop:

```
df$contain <- NA #create a new column

df$contain <- for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  paste('Contains(TR.CommonName,\'', df[i,1], '\')')
  }
```

The prompt is not giving me any error and the command above is simply deleting the new created column. I could not figure out what I am doing wrong and any help is appreciated.

my desired output would be

```
      companyName    contain
1     Apple          Contains(TR.CommonName,Apple)
2     Microsoft      Contains(TR.CommonName,Microsoft)
3     Perspectives   Contains(TR.CommonName,Perspectives)
4     Jet            Contains(TR.CommonName,Jet)
5     Icontel AG     Contains(TR.CommonName,Icontel AG)
6     Intel          Contains(TR.CommonName,Intel)
```

Comment: `paste` is vectoriszed.  So just need `df$contain <- paste('Contains(TR.CommonName,', df$companyName)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
df$contains <- paste0("Contains(TR.CommonName,", df$companyName, ")")
```